# Proof of $~FV \left(\lambda xyz ~.~xxy \right)=\emptyset $

Tags: type-theory

I want to prove that $~ \lambda xyz ~.~xxy ~$ is a closed $\lambda$-term $~ \mathit{i.e.}~ FV \left(\lambda xyz ~.~xxy \right)=\emptyset  ~$

The followings is my try.

$$\begin{align}
\lambda xyz ~.~xxy&= \lambda x ~.~ \left(\lambda yz ~.~ xxy \right)
\\&=\lambda x ~.~ \left( \lambda y ~.~\left(\lambda z ~.~xxy \right) \right)
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
FV \left(\lambda x ~.~ \left( \lambda y ~.~\left(\lambda z ~.~xxy \right) \right) \right)&=FV \left( \left( \lambda y ~.~\left(\lambda z ~.~xxy \right) \right)\right)\setminus\{x\}\\
&=\left(FV \left( \lambda z ~.~xxy \right)\setminus\{y\} \right)\setminus\{x\}\\
&=\left( \left(  \color{fuchsia}{FV\left( xxy \right)}  \setminus\{z\} \right)\setminus\{y\} \right)\setminus\{x\}
\end{align}$$

I've stucked to proceed calculation from $~ FV(xxy) ~$

I am only given the definitions of $~ FV ~$ as below.

$$\begin{cases}
FV(x)=\{x\}\\
FV(M~N)=FV(M)\bigcup FV(N)\\
FV \left(\lambda x ~.~M \right)=FV(M)\setminus\{x\}
\end{cases}$$

How can I handle $~ FV(xxy) ~$?

Comment: $FV(xxy) = FV(x (xy)) = FV(x) \cup FV(xy) = ... = \{x,y\}$

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of $~ FV ~$, single variables are free variables of lambda terms.

So simply we can confirm that the following is true.

$$FV(xxy)=\{x,y\}~\text{or}~\{x,x,y\}$$

IDK whether my this claim is true.